# GAE+Objectify class hierarchy and refs(...)

Tags: java, generics, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I've the following classes:

1. `Streamable` interface
2. `DiaryEntry` implements `Streamable`
3. `StatusEntry` implements `Streamable`

And a `stream` field that is a `LinkedList<Ref<? extends Streamable>>`, which (in my mind) should contains both `Ref<DiaryEntry>` and `Ref<StatusEntry>`.

Unfortunately seems i'm wrong because i get a compile error at this line:

```
ofy().load().refs(stream).values();
```

The error is:

`The method refs(Iterable<Ref<E>>) in the type Loader is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList<Ref<? extends Streamable>>)`

Is it possible that i've modeled my entities or field in some bad way? 
Should the `refs` method have this signature `refs(Iterable<Ref<? extends E>>)` instead of the current one?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided enough information in your question. What class declares `E` and what are that type parameter's bounds? Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `E` is the parameter type used by Objectify...

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything. Update the question with all the information that's needed to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information in your question to get the whole picture, for example what class declares `E` and what that type parameter's bounds are.

But to hazard a guess, try redeclaring `refs` to take an `Iterable<? extends Ref<? extends E>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Objectify works with a List of Interface members. I believe you would see an exception saying constructor missing for `Streamable`. According to me, the best way to work with this is to have concrete classes. In that case `List<Ref<Streamable_Concrete_Class>>` can handle other classes extending `Streamable_Concrete_Class`. After the List is persisted, @Load annotation for the List should work as expected